# How to send json object to the Controller JsonResult Method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass a JSON object that can have many elements, I tried it with the following code:

```
var app = new Vue({
   el: '#crearMetaCompuesta',
   data: {
      inputmin: 0,
      inputmax: 0,
      inputres: 0,
      rangos_creados: [{
         min: 1,
         max: 2,
         result: 3
      }]
   },
   methods: {
      additem: function() {

         let nuevoItem = {
            min: this.inputmin,
            max: this.inputmax,
            result: this.inputres,

         }

         this.rangos_creados.push(nuevoItem);
      },
      guardarMetaCompuesta: function() {

         console.log(JSON.stringify(this.rangos_creados));

         axios.post('@Url.Action("GuardarMetaCompuesta")', {
               msg: JSON.stringify(app.rangos_creados),
               id: 7
            }, {
               headers: {
                  'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
               }
            }).then(function(response) {
               alert(response);
               console.log("--------->" + JSON.stringify(app.rangos_creados));
            })
            .catch(function(e) {
               console.log("---------> |" + e);
            });
      }
   }
})
```

the JSONResult Method:

```
public class MetasCompuestasClass{
    public string min { get; set; }
    public string max { get; set; }
    public string result { get; set; }
}


public JsonResult GuardarMetaCompuesta(MetasCompuestasClass msg, int id) {
  //here I put a breakpoint but the variable arrives null
    var x = 1;
    return Json(new { result = false, message = msg }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

but the `msg` variable always arrives null.

How should I send the object or what 'headers' should I place so that the variable does not arrive null and I can save the elements of type `MetasCompuestasClass`?

Comment: Try `JSON.stringify({
               msg: this.rangos_creados,
               id: 7
            })`

Comment: I did it, even the variable 'id' also assigned an element of the instance, 'id' arrives correctly, 'msg' keeps coming null, I print it before sending it to make sure that no null is sent from JavaScript  { msg: JSON.stringify(this.rangos_creados), id: this.inputres }

Comment: No, I meant stringify the whole object, not just `msg`. Like this: `axios.post('@Url.Action("GuardarMetaCompuesta")', JSON.stringify({ msg: this.rangos_creados, id: 7 }),...`  Otherwise `msg` will be a string and won't be casted to `MetasCompuestasClass`.

Comment: is improving, 'msg' has arrived as a variable of type 'MetasCompuestasClass', however its elements are arriving null, 'min', 'max' and 'result'

Comment: In addition to that, as Topher answer suggests, `rangos_creados` is an array. Either send `this.rangos_creados[0]` or change the parameter to `List<MetasCompuestasClass>`

Comment: YES! This worked for me thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your `rangos_creados` object is an array, and you're expecting a single object in your Action.

Try with the Action signature like this:

```
public JsonResult GuardarMetaCompuesta(List<MetasCompuestasClass> msg, int id) {
```

Or, if you didn't mean to make that an array because you're always only passing one item to the api action, change `rangos_creados` declaration to an object, and map the `nuevoItem` properties to it, or just update the `rangos_creados` with the values instead of using nuevoItem and don't push it into the collection anymore. 
But that Depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: this worked for me, thanks !, also changing the way to form the json:
 axios.post('@Url.Action("GuardarMetaCompuesta")', JSON.stringify({ msg: app.rangos_creados})

Comment: Great, glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're sending **app.** instead of **this.**

`JSON.stringify(app.rangos_creados)` vs. `JSON.stringify(this.rangos_creados)`

Keep in mind that **this** may be a different context in this scenario.

Comment: I've already tried it that way, but it does not work either :/

Comment: Can you monitor the network tab of developer tools and see what is being posted?  If msg is missing or empty, that would point to the JavaScript.